# .NET Remove event handler and destroy invoked events

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

On the main form of my app, I have one event handler that is called from a different thread than UI because it is an event generated by a hardware device.
To sync. with the GUI thread, when the event is called, I do Form.BeginInvoke().
The call is then queued in the Message Loop.

When the user needs to close the form, before closing I remove the handler for the Event, but it seems that invoked calls could still be called.
Then if the routine to handle the event uses some information that is no longer available at the time that it is called, I can have problems.

For example:

```
Private MyDevice as New SomeDevice()
Private MyGlobalVar as MyVarType

Public Sub OnDeviceEvent()

   If InvokeRequired Then
      BeginInvoke(Sub() OnDeviceEvent())
      Return
   End If

   If MyGlobalVar.Field = 0 then
    'do something
   end if

End Sub

Public Sub PrepareToCloseForm()

   'removes the handler of the event
   RemoveHandler MyDevice.DeviceEvent, AddressOf OnDeviceEvent

   MyGlobalVar = Nothing 

End Sub
```

Using the code above, right after I run PrepareToCloseForm() sometimes I get an object Null error on the following line:

```
If MyGlobalVar.Field = 0 then
```

I could do a Null check before I use the variable, but as I have many other events, I would like a more elegant solution.
How can I make sure that Invoked calls will not happen after I removed the handler?

Should I call DoEvents before I remove all the handlers to process pending messages?

Comment: Eventhandler will not be executed after you have removed it. But there are possible "race condition" case when `DeveiceEvent` was raised before you removed handler and access `MyGlobalVar` after it already set to `Nothing`.  What is purpose of global variable? Can you consider instead of using global variable - pass value to the handler? With your current design checking for null will be simplest solution - you can introduce method which return required value and check for null in that method

Comment: Per Eric Lippert's blog post here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/29/events-and-races/ "...event handlers are required to be robust in the face of being called even after the event has been unsubscribed."

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have is that if you closed the thing and set MyGlobalVar to Nothing, even if the OnDeviceEvent checks that, it could become nothing at any time while you're still trying to use it.  To get around this, you could put a SyncLock around access to MyGlobalVar

```
Private MyDevice as SomeDevice()
Private MyGlobalVar as MyVarType
Private SyncLockObject as New Object

Public Sub OnDeviceEvent()

   If InvokeRequired Then
      BeginInvoke(Sub() OnDeviceEvent())
      Return
   End If

   SyncLock SyncLockObject
      If MyGlobalVar IsNot Nothing Then
         If MyGlobalVar.Field = 0 then
          'do something
        End If
      End If
  End SyncLock

End Sub

Public Sub PrepareToCloseForm()

   'removes the handler of the event
   RemoveHandler MyDevice.DeviceEvent, AddressOf OnDeviceEvent

   SyncLock SyncLockObject
      MyGlobalVar = Nothing 
   End SyncLock

End Sub
```

That way, you can't set MyGlobalVar to nothing while OnDeviceEvent is accessing it and you can't access it OnDeviceEvent can't access it while PrepareToCloseForm is setting it to Nothing

Comment: But if I understand correctly, this will not solve the problem that I described. You see, the invoked method could be called (because of message queue) after the Synclock exited already on the PrepareToCloseForm, and it will be able to acquire and enter the lock normally, and still will give null reference error inside the event handler.

Comment: Oh, sorry.  I added a check inside the SyncLock to make sure it's not Nothing.

Comment: But `MyGlobalVar` can be accessed in event handler after it set to `Nothing` in `PrepareToCloseForm` method. Adding checking for null is exactly what OP trying to avoid and asked us for different approach

Comment: The SyncLock insures that won't happen.  While the event handler is inside the SyncLock, the close method can't set it to Nothing and vice versa